# Format time python

Tags: python, time, format

I have his line in python. I would like it to output month and year as MM/YYYY. What is the best way to do this.

```
time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)))
```

Current output:

```
Wed Sep 26 08:57:26 2012
```

I would like 9/2012

Comment: use [time.strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime)

Answer (score 2):

```
ts = os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(dir_path, file_name))
print(time.strftime('%m/%Y', time.gmtime(ts)))
```

Comment: I'm not sure about how you want to handle timezones here, but this will give you the month/year in GMT.  If you want it in local time, I think that you need `time.localtime(ts)` instead of `time.gmtime(ts)`.

Comment: I don't care too much about the time zone. My goal is to detect mxds (esri's map documents, ArcGIS) that have been modified in the last three years and if so I need to point all of the data sources to our new database.

Answer (score 2):

`time.ctime` is documented to return a "string representing local time".  It doesn't say what that string is (or how it's formatted), so I assume it's probably platform specific.

Instead, you'll probably want to use `datetime`.

```
secs = os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(dir_path, file_name))
date = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(secs)
formatted = date.strftime('%m/%Y')
```